# How to convert an std::string to an unsigned char[] array *properly*. I think I did it wrong, someone point me in the right direction?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, buffer, byte

I'm currently reverse engineering a network protocol and I wrote a small decryption protocol.

I used to define the bytes of the packet into an unsigned character array, as so:

```
unsigned char buff[] = "\x00\xFF\x0A" etc.
```

In order to not recompile the program multiple times per packet I made a small GUI tool where it would get the bytes in \xFF notation from a string. I did this the following way:

```
int length = int(stencString.length());
unsigned char *buff = new unsigned char[length+1];
memcpy(buff, stencString.c_str(), length+1);
```

When I call my function it gives me a proper decryption when I hardcode it using the prior method but it gives me garbage then the rest of my string when I memcpy from the string to the array. The creepy part? They both have the same print output!

Here's how I'm using it:
http://pastie.org/private/kndfbaqgvmjiuwlounss9g

Here's kdxalgo.h (c) Luigi Auriemma:
http://pastie.org/private/7dzemmwyyqtngiamlxy8tw

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do a binary comparison to make sure the hardcoded version really matched your "decoded" version?

Comment: What advantage are you getting not just leaving it in the string? (Use `std::vector` for a character buffer, by the way.)

Comment: I don't think this is your issue but you can copy out of the buffer out of the std::string without using the c_str() function, call the .data() member function instead:

```memcpy(buff, stencString.data(), length)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what happens when you use the following for the hardcoded version of buff.

```
unsigned char buff[] =
"\\xd3\\x8c\\x38\\x6b\\x82\\x4c\\xe1\\x1e"
"\\x6b\\x7a\\xff\\x4c\\x9d\\x73\\xbe\\xab"
"\\x38\\xc7\\xc5\\xb8\\x71\\x8f\\xd5\\xbb"
"\\xfa\\xb9\\xf3\\x7a\\x43\\xdd\\x12\\x41"
"\\x4b\\x01\\xa2\\x59\\x74\\x60\\x1e\\xe0"
"\\x6d\\x68\\x26\\xfa\\x0a\\x63\\xa3\\x88";
```

I have a suspicion that it will produce the same output as you entering the following: `\xd3\x8c\x38\x6b\x82\x4c\xe1\x1e\x6b\x7a\xff\x4c\x9d\x73\xbe\xab\x38\xc7\xc5\xb8\x71\x8f\xd5\xbb\xfa\xb9\xf3\x7a\x43\xdd\x12\x41\x4b\x01\xa2\x59\x74\x60\x1e\xe0\x6d\x68\x26\xfa\x0a\x63\xa3\x88`.

The compiler automatically takes "\xd3" and converts it into the expected underlying binary representation. You need to have a method of converting the characters backslash, x, d, 3 into the same binary representation.

---

If you are certain that you will receive properly formated input, then the answer isn't too hard:

```
unsigned char c2h(char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case '0': return  0;
        case '1': return  1;
        case '2': return  2;
        case '3': return  3;
        case '4': return  4;
        case '5': return  5;
        case '6': return  6;
        case '7': return  7;
        case '8': return  8;
        case '9': return  9;
        case 'a': return 10;
        case 'b': return 11;
        case 'c': return 12;
        case 'd': return 13;
        case 'e': return 14;
        case 'f': return 15;
    }
}

std::string handle_hex(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < str.length(); index += 4) // skip to next hex digit
    {
        // str[index + 0] is '\\' and str[index + 1] is 'x'
        unsigned char ch = c2h(str[index+2]) * 16 + c2h(str[index+3]);
        result.append((char)ch);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Again assuming perfect formatting, so there is not error handling. I know that I'll lose some points for this answer because it's not the best way of doing this, but I want to make the algorithm as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: Wait, what would I have to do next then? You're absolutely right, it produces the same wrong output!

Comment: @DavidStancu: You will need to parse the string and convert to the characters that you want.

Comment: That should not be too complex :) If you can allow for a format change, it can actually be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as Jeffery points out, is that the compiler processes the `\xd3` and generates a character with that value, but when you read into a string `\xd3` you are actually reading 4 characters: `\`, `x`, `d` and `3`.

You will need to read the string, and then parse it into valid contents. For a simple approach, you can change the format so that the input is a space separated sequence of characters encoded as `0xd3` (as this is really simple to parse):

```
std::string buffer;
std::string input( "0xd3 0x8c 0x38" ); // this would be read
std::istringstream in( input );
in >> std::hex;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int>( in ),
           std::istream_iterator<int>(),
           std::back_inserter( buffer ) );
```

Of course, there is no need to change the format, you can process it. For that you will only need to read one character at a time. When you encounter a `\` then read the next character, if it is `x` then read the next two characters (say `ch1` and `ch2`) and transform them into an integer value:

```
int value_of_hex( char ch ) {
   if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
      return ch-'0';
   if (tolower(ch) >= 'a' && tolower(ch) <= 'f')
      return 10 + toupper(ch) - 'a';
   // error
   throw std::runtime_error( "Invalid input" );
}
value = value_of_hex( ch1 )*16 + value_of_hex( ch2 );
```